# Want to Parse raw string coming from Java UI upon user selection to SQL query String?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, parsing

I am wondering how can I parse raw string coming from webapp Java UI upon user selection to SQL query String in Java !
 For Example : On UI, I have 100 companies (and also a database having info about these companies) and if suppose user selected two companies from UI and clicked search button then It should return all information about these two companies comp1 and comp2 and relationships among these two companies and fetch following query from sql database :
**The table CompanyData contains all general information about companies like  ID, Name, CEO, Stablishment year, Awards won, global ranks, etc....
Table ComapanyDomain contains information about the domains, technologies and expertise of companies,**

```
SELECT * FROM CompanyData
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CompnayDomain
              WHERE companyName = "comp1" 
              and ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM CompnayDomain
                          WHERE companyName = "comp2"))
```

the string to be parsed It would look like  `" Company comp1 and comp2 "` in above scenario

Thank you

Comment: What does the string you want to parse look like?

Comment: Not sure I followed.. a sample of data and expected output would help

Comment: off-topic: the sub sql can be written in better way? does this generate same output `... FROM CompanyData WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CompnayDomain WHERE companyName IN ("comp1","comp2"))` ?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk , Hey , Really very sorry I forgot to put the string to be parsed It would look like  " Company comp1 and comp2 " in above scenario which I discussed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it like this (I didn't use your sql query because it didn't make any sense at all, it would return always an empty set unless 2 companies have the same ID)

```
    String input = "Company comp1 and comp2";

    String data = input.substring(8, input.length());
    String [] companies = data.split("\\b and \\b");

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CompanyData WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CompanyDomain WHERE companyName IN (";

    for(int i = 0; i < companies.length - 1; i++) {
        sql += "?,"
    }

    sql += "?)";

    for(int i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
        // Use prepared statement and insert the values here
    }
```